# How to clear browser cache in Selenium test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-cache

I am running my Selenium tests with WebDriver. I am repeating the tests with some loop so now I want to Clear the cache before starting new test in JAVA.

```
@Test
public void ffAndIe() throws InterruptedException {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 5000){

        driver.get("http://dit-map.appspot.com/");
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        driver.get("http://dit- map.appspot.com/#home:zoom=7&lat=37.04&lng=25.05&display=weather");
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        driver.get("http://dit-map.appspot.com/#home:zoom=9&lat=37.55&lng=23.83&display=weather,wind");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.get("http://dit-map.appspot.com/#home:zoom=9&lat=37.84&lng=23.22&display=weather,wind,cloud");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.get("http://dit-map.appspot.com/?lang=en#home:zoom=10&lat=38.13&lng=22.59&display=weather,wind,meteogram");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        i++;
    }
}
```

with in this while loop the first thing I want to do is to CLEAR my CACHE (IE, MOZILLA & CHROME)

any idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: In IE I managed this to some degree by setting the lowest disk space for IE cache and option which is called something like "always check updated page" (I do not have English XP, so cannot tell its exact name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear Firefox cache in Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378331/clear-firefox-cache-in-selenium-ide)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to clear the cache through the web driver API.  However, if you can start a new instance of the browser each time, the cache should be cleared in [FF](http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/f0c1c83f091bf408/e70fdf5ee521cd4c) and [Chrome](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/517d599ebadbf7c4/f9d1f6eacefcf84a) because a new profile is created on each launch.

The comments for [issue #40 (Clear cache)](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=40)  in the Selenium issue tracker list two potential solutions to your problem if creating a new browser instance isn't possible:

1. [Clear the IE cache](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/clear-ie7-browsing-history-from-the-command-line/) from the command line
2. [Disable the FF cache](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=40#c2) using a custom profile

HTH

Answer (score 0):

DT_IE_AGENT_ACTIVE=true activates the Add-On so that it collects data from the current browser session

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

I have used this lines of code in python to do that and it seems to clear the cache every time(Internet Explorer)

capab = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER

capab.clear()