# Clear Firefox cache in Selenium IDE

Tags: firefox, selenium

I'm using Selenium IDE to test a web application. Sometimes my tests succeed even though they should have failed. The reason is that the browser happens to load a previous version of a page from the cache instead of loading the newer version of that page. In other words, I might introduce a bug to my app without being aware of it because the tests may pass after loading a previous working version instead of loading the new buggy version.

The best solution I could have thought of is to delete the browser cache before running the tests. I have a Selenium script in which I run set-up selenium commands before running the tests. Is there a selenium command to clear Firefox cache? Alternatively, is there another way to prevent loading pages from the cache during the tests?

Answer (score 14):

In Python this should disable Firefox cache:

```py
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.cache.offline.enable", False)
profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the cache in firefox profile.
See this [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=40#c2) for more details.

Comment: In case you're too lazy to click the link.  Create a FirefoxPofile and set set preferences for browser cache like so.

user_pref("browser.cache.disk.enable", false);

user_pref("browser.cache.memory.enable", false);

user_pref("browser.cache.offline.enable", false);

user_pref("network.http.use-cache", false);

Worked for me.

Comment: Am I missing something? I figured out via Google how to create a new profile, but where do I add these settings? And how do I ensure selenium opens Firefox with this profile instead of my regular one?

Comment: Just disabling cookies won't serve the compelete purpose. Because there are few page like a checkout page which requires you to be using cookies.Is there a way to delete history as we do manuaaly using selenium

Answer (score 1):

For those programming in Java, here is how I solve the issue:

```java
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("browser.cache.disk.enable", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.cache.memory.enable", false);
    profile.setPreference("browser.cache.offline.enable", false);
    profile.setPreference("network.http.use-cache", false);
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setProfile(profile);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I've never had to do this before (clearing the cookies has always been sufficient for me), but from what I can see, this is functionality that is lacking in the current builds of Selenium, although from recent changelogs, it looks like the developers are making a push to make a standard way of doing this. In `2.33` of `iedriverserver`, They have the following changenote:

> Introduced ability to clean browser cache before launching IE. This version
>      introduces the ie.ensureCleanSession capability, which will clear the
>      browser cache, history, and cookies before launching IE. When using this
>      capability, be aware that this clears the cache for all running instances of
>      Internet Explorer. Using this capability while attempting to run multiple
>      instances of the IE driver may cause unexpected behavior. Note this also
>      will cause a performance drop when launching the browser, as the driver will
>      wait for the cache clearing process to complete before actually launching
>      IE

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG

To do this, you would specify this at driver creation time in the `DesiredCapabilities` Map using `ensureCleanSession`.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

Since you're using firefox, it looks like you're out of luck in using a native way to do this. If you haven't tried `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();`, I'd try that to see if it gets you where you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

For C# and Geckodriver v0.31.0

```cs
public Task<WebDriver> newInstance()
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("geckodriver"))
                {                   
                    process.Kill();
                }

                FirefoxProfileManager profilemanager = new FirefoxProfileManager();

                System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<String> profilesList = profilemanager.ExistingProfiles;

                foreach (String profileFound in profilesList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(profileFound);
                }

                FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

                FirefoxProfile profile = profilemanager.GetProfile("default");

                //profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

                profile.SetPreference("browser.cache.disk.enable", false);
                profile.SetPreference("browser.cache.memory.enable", false);
                profile.SetPreference("browser.cache.offline.enable", false);
                profile.SetPreference("network.http.use-cache", false);

                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

                return driver;
            });
        }
```