# Multiple tests on the same IEdriver instance - memory issues

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm running lots of selenium tests on my node which is windows machine. In order to speed up test execution by avoiding starting/closing IEDriver instance after every test I decided to reuse the same driver instance for every test. Everything works fine with firefox and chrome, but IE11 is having serious issues. After about 30 minutes IE freezes without any exception and execution stops, it completely loses connection with my node. I can see that IE11 process (iexplore.exe) uses massive memory resources (1.5 GB or more) and I need to kill it using task manager to shut it down.

Did anyone face this kind of issues and how to avoid it (except to create new driver instance for every test), is it even possible to run many test on the same IEdriver instance?

I'm using IEDriver 3.0.0, Internet Explorer 11. Same thing on windows server 2012 and windows 8.1 machines.

Comment: I have the same issue. Selenium guys close iedriver issues with the reason "it is an issue of ie browser not ie driver".
So we can only driver.close() after some tests and reopen it back to do some more tests.

Comment: Every time is it opening in new tab or new window without closing the previous one.

Comment: I'm using a same window, if I open new window/driver instance it will work fine, that is exactly the problem, I want to avoid reopening driver instance.

Comment: Can u chec k this link if it is helpful. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/ie-11-high-memory-ram-usage/19a4d22b-2b92-461b-a8a1-ae01798a9a32

Comment: It's general IE issue so I'm not optimistic about it, but will give it a try in next few days. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's using a lot of cache. Maybe you're requestinga quite extensive website?

Probably solutions I see:

- Restart the driver using `driver.quit()` (might need to much time)
- Try clearing the cache. (maybe using https://stackoverflow.com/a/54944115/20443541)
- Block Ads (for example using a extension)
- Porting to Chrome (I think it uses less RAM and is more optimised for Selenium