# T2.micro running python scraper - uncontrolable CPU

Tags: python, selenium, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phantomjs

I have a web **scraper** setup on a t2.micro EC2 instance running Ubuntu.
The **scraper** is written in Python, it uses Selenium and PhantomJS. The data it gets is sent to a separate RDS instance.
I set a cronjob to run the script every 15 minutes, which it does.
Here is my problem:
[image: My CPU activity]

The script runs well (red boxes) and all of a sudden, it gets over utilized and my instance gets really slow.
My script goes from running in a few seconds to 10 minutes of just doesn't run.
During these bursts, the instance uses CPU credits. However, my CPU credits have been going up. I've found that rebooting the instance solves the problem.
Any idea on what is happening?

Comment: I have a same issue on IEdriver instance (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679405/multiple-tests-on-the-same-iedriver-instance-memory-issues) and found no solution yet, only rebooting of the instance helps. :/

Comment: I've setup an automatic reboot if the CPU goes above its usual for 10 minutes to get around the problem but I'd rather not have to reboot it...

Comment: Apparently, closing PhantomJS after running the script doesn't shut down the phantomjs process. Even worse, it creates a new one every time the script starts running.

Comment: Just add a `killall phantomjs` at the end of the script

Comment: Have you observed what's going on using `top` or `htop`?  Note that as long as your CPU credit balance is not approaching zero, the problem will be the code you're running, not the behavior of the instance...  t2 doesn't slow down until your credits are almost depleted.

Comment: Yeah I gad plenty of phantomjs processes running all for nothing. Haven't had any problems since I added that bash command at the end of my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been experiencing the same problem, when I upgraded to a t2.medium the python script ran much faster.  If your using python I would recommend using [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil)

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == 'phantomjs':
        proc.kill()
```

put that at the end of your code, the browser can sometimes suck all your memory and slow down the script especially if your running a selenium in a loop.