# Selenium ChromeDriver incrementally becomes slower over a short period of time time

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium with chromedriver to do some pretty basic screen-scraping, but as I loop and wait for elements and then click on links - the process becomes so slow it's unusable. If I dispose of the chromedriver instance and new-up another instance, everything starts out fast again.

**Why is this getting slow so quickly? What can I do to speed this up?**

Pseudo C# code:

```
while(true)
{
    var dataGridRows = browser.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@class='datadrid-row']"));

    foreach (var dataGridRow in dataGridRows)
    {
        OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions act = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(browser.Driver);

        //Double click on the grid row. A new dialog (CSS style) will show up.
        act.DoubleClick(dataGridRow).Build().Perform();

        // This first time I double click the grid row, the dialog pops up within a few miliseconds.
        //  This gets incrementally slower, about 10 iterations later the popup will take several MINUTES to show up after the double-click.

        //This line waits for a "close dialog" button to appear. This is where the delay occurs but this returns as soon as the dialog actually appears.
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> closeButtons = browser.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@class='dilog-close-button']"));

        CollectScreenScrapeInformation(...);
    }

    Sleep(1000 * 60);
}
```

Comment: The `closeButtons` line doesn't wait for anything. It just scrapes the page for the XPath dialog close button. My guess is that you are setting an implicit wait somewhere which is causing the issue. Also, are you mixing implicit and explicit waits? The docs say don't do that because it can cause unpredictable wait times.

Comment: Have you tried this scenario manually? Maybe it's the site. Have you tried FF or a different browser driver? Does it behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Driver itself is not eating your memory, it's the browser. Yes, creating new driver instance speeds things up, but it's not new `chromedriver.exe` instance which speeds it up, it's fresh `chrome.exe` instance. If you perform your problematic scripts manually (try to click and abuse your page for 10 min and see what happens) you'll find the same issues, browsers will get slower.
But I must admit that in my experience chrome is the fastest and best performing driver, `firefoxdriver` has more memory issues when the same instance is used a lot, and `IEdriver` is impossible to use when you have only one instance for a longer time ([Multiple tests on the same IEdriver instance - memory issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679405/multiple-tests-on-the-same-iedriver-instance-memory-issues)). Even `phantomJS/ghostdriver` has this kind of isssues.

tldr; Recreate your driver instance if it gets slower over time.