# Selenium IE11 - Failed to open http://localhost:4200

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am encountering a weird error in Selenium + IE11 under some very specific circumstances.

We run Selenium tests which reuse the same browser window. At some point it stops loading the site. I reloaded it manually and briefly saw `Failed to open http://localhost:4200`:

[image]

After a second it loads the html page but I think it loads it from cache, and the page stays stuck at the "loading..." progress indicator.

The Network Tab in F12 for some reason stops rendering (this is how it looks after a resized the window a couple of times - you can clearly see the artifacts from previous repaint events):

[image]

If I open a new tab it works from there. Once IE11 gets stuck at that "state", I can't make it work in the same tab, even if I delete site data with Ctrl+Shift+Del.

Any ideas what is happening? I couldn't find anything at all about this `Failed to open <URL>` error by googing.

Comment: You can try to make a test in compatibility mode. You can also try to enable the option 'Always refresh from server' in Network tab in developer tools. These are the things you can try to check from IE side. Further you can check that whether server breaks the connection or not.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason when looking at Process Explorer.

[image]

I also found this open issue in GitHub:

[IEDriverServer causes memory leaks in iexplore.exe #3861](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3861)

> The thing is that we're testing a complex scenarios on a very heavy application and when IE consumes more than approx 1.5 GBytes it just hangs.
>   And moreover even running the simple driver.findElement(By) scenario during the number of hours leads to IE hanging without releasing the memory.

I also found this SO question:
[Multiple tests on the same IEdriver instance - memory issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679405/multiple-tests-on-the-same-iedriver-instance-memory-issues)