# How to change the value of firefox cache size in Selenium IDE for Python2?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

It is possible to change the cache size value in Firefox of the browser using `browser.cache.disk.capacity` like mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475584/cache-size-of-firefox).

I tried to adapt the code suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378331/clear-firefox-cache-in-selenium-ide)

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.capacity", 9113600)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

But this didn't work and still resulted in

[image]

How can I change the value of the cache size in Firefox using Selenium IDE with python2 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to figure out and it wasn't that much difficult.

First, check what profiles you have in `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`. I suggest you use the default one. You can also create new profiles using the command line `firefox -p` to display the profile at startup.

In `~/.mozilla/firefox/`, you will find also folders like `ng6ufigq.default` which contains the configuration parameters for that profile, specifically, `prefs.js`. Open this file and change `browser.cache.disk.capacity` to any desired value then save it.

Finally, in the python script:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('~/.mozilla/firefox/ng6ufigq.default')
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

The script will then launch with the given profile settings.